Map a nested object in a dto to a set of objects using Mapstruct
As the title suggests i want to map a object to a set or list of objects using Mapstruct
I want The category DTO to be mapped to or added to the set of Categories
How can i do that with mapstruct
public class Brand {

    private Long id;    
    private String name;    
    private String description;    
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();   
    private Set<SubCategory> subcategories = new HashSet<>();

}

public class BrandDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private CategoryDTO category;

}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you want to map your CategoryDTO into a Category-Set and/or SubCategory-Set you can write a custom mapping for that by yourself:
@Mapping(target = "categories", source = "category")
@Mapping(target = "subCategories", source = "category")
abstract Brand toBrand(BrandDTO brandDto);

Set<Category> toCategories(CategoryDTO categoryDto) {
    // your custom logic here
    return Set.of();
}

Set<SubCategory> toSubCategories(CategoryDTO categoryDto) {
    // your custom logic here
    return Set.of();
}

Or do you have an existing Brand object and want to add the (sub-)categories from the CategoryDTO to it? In that case Mapstruct won't really help you since its Codegeneration seems not usefil fot this usecase. But theoretically you could still press the logic in the Mapper. E.g. with @AfterMapping:
@Mapping(target = "categories", source = "brand.categories")
@Mapping(target = "subCategories", source = "brand.subCategories")
abstract Brand toBrand(Brand brand, CategoryDTO categoryDto);

@AfterMapping
protected void toBrandAfterMapping(@MappingTarget Brand brand, CategoryDTO categoryDto) {
    Category categoryFromDto = null; // your custom logic here
    SubCategory subCategoryFromDto = null; // your custom logic here

    brand.addCategory(categoryFromDto);
    brand.addSubcategory(subCategoryFromDto);
}

